# How do I paste the same line of code X times but change one word in the line each time?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, replace, filetype-html

I'm writing HTML lists, and I want to be able to automagically paste 10 list items where the item text is the only thing that changes.

I could accomplish this using PHP and then just copying the rendered HTML code but if there's a way to skip that step and do it directly from Vim that would save me so much time.

Comment: Have a look at the plugin https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim, it may suits your need. Otherwise you can use a macro to do so, do you know the text in advance?

Comment: Yes I know what text I want to put in each item. Thank you for the plugin suggestion I'll take a look at home tonight and also look into Vim macros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For what you want to do, [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim), as nobe4 suggested, is your best bet.

In insert mode, `li{item $}*10<c-y>,` will expand 10 `<li>`s with `item N` prefilled as the text.  You'll start editing the contents of the first one.  While still in insert mode, pressing `<c-y>n` will move to the next tag for editing.

If your list items are not a sequence repeated text, you can use [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) to help.

Example list of text that needs to be wrapped:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

If you start with your cursor somewhere in the text, pressing `^vip$<c-v>Stli<cr>` will wrap each line with `<li></li>`.

```
^     - move to the first column
vip   - select the paragraph
$     - Move to the last column in the selection
<c-v> - Convert the visual selection into a block. Without the
        previous $, it would only select 1 column.
St    - Start vim-surround's tag entry
li    - The tag name
<cr>  - Enter
```

This can be made into an easy to use key map:

```
nmap <leader>li ^vip$<c-v>Stli<cr>
```

Comment: You have saved my fingers much agony. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @Azmodeus Glad it helped.  vim-surround is such a productivity booster that you should take the time to follow along with its docs.  And just in case you did't know, emmet-vim will work in pre-compiled stylesheets like sass or less.  For example, try this in a scss file: `.col$*5>.inner`

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do this with a mapping:

```
 :nmap ^B o<li></li>^[4hi
```

The plan is to insert to tags and then place the insert inbetween them, so that you can type in the text, escape back into normal mode and then do ctrl-b again. (PS, the ^B and ^[ are entered using ctrl_V, but you probably knew that already.) To put in ten rows in single command, you can use

```
10ctrl_b
```

I was not clear if you have some automagic way of actually creating the item text?